# Why does this look different on FF vs. Chrome vs. IE?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm trying to make some graphs on a number line (think math class) with HTML and CSS.

Here's what I've got: http://jsfiddle.net/3pKrj/2/

1.) It looks good on FF.
2.) On Chrome it's mostly good, but the arrowheads at the beginning and end of the line are about 1 px too high.  There are also tiny dots in the middle of the red line.
3.) Of course, IE fails miserably.
4.) I don't know about Safari b/c I don't have it.

It seems that the `top: ___px;` part is being interpreted differently by the different browsers.  Any ideas on how to make all browsers display it as FF currently does?

Comment: FYI, comments in CSS are `/* like this */`, not `// like this`. Even though it seems to work in your fiddle, that's not the right way to do it.

Comment: Using tables for this is the wrong way to go. Look at JavaScript libraries who specialize in those sorts of things.

Comment: Use [css reset](http://www.cssreset.com/).

Comment: @Madara Uchiha: Such as?

Comment: @Vucko: Looks interesting.  How do I use this?

Comment: my css comments are /** like this **/